# How to publish an application that it will be available only by link?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app that I would like to publish, but I want it to be available only by link(exclude it from general search on PlayMarket).

I know that there is such approach:

https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/how-to-publish-private-apps-in-google-play/

But it is now exactly what I need, because I need to add organization Id

> Input the organization ID and name for each organization you wish to publish the app to. Click Add.

Also there is an option to publish an app in alpha or beta, but it is also not exactly what I need, because in alpha you can share not more that 20 and in beta not more that 200...

So, question is: how to publish an app that it will be available by link without any restriction?

Answer (score 0):

You can release your application using internal release of the play store. This way, you can manually add your targets using email or send them a link which by clicking on it, they automatically will be added to your internal testing program.

Comment: I am not sure that this way is good to share an app with customers... This way is suitable if you gonna to share your app with testers... This is official docs https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479 take a look on section `How authorized testers turn on internal app sharing`, firstly testers requested to open sharing options that download some certificates... No, it is not the way to share an app with customers...